# How to pack v8 snapshot into exe using electron-builder?

Tags: node.js, electron, exe, v8, electron-builder

I made custom v8 snapshot for my Electron app and put it into `\node_modules\electron\dist` and it's been working fine until I packed the app. I figured out that there's default `v8_context_snapshot.bin` in `win-unpacked` insted of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [afterPack](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#afterpack) hook into your build configuration. In that script you should copy your bin to unpacked (e.g. `'\dist\win-unpacked\'`).